# Which bipolar stepper motor can be used with EasyDriver4.5V A3967?

Tags: pi-4, hardware

I have EasyDriver 4.5V A3967 driver and planning to purchase 12V bipolar stepper motor with specs

phase: 2 phase
voltage: 12 V
current: 0.7 A.
Phase resistance:
4.0 ± 10% Ω
phase inductance: 3.2 ± 20% mH
phase holding togque: 14 Ncm
insulation class: B step angle: 1.8 ± 5%

Will this work with raspberry pi 4 B and EasyDriver I have.

Regards
S

Comment: not all of your post is on topic here ... the question that asks if EasyDriver can be interfaced with a Raspberry Pi is on topic here ... but a question that asks if the motor will work with the EasyDriver is off topic, because it is not about the Raspberry Pi